# POWERSHELL: Create Task - RunLevel Highest Access Denied

Tags: powershell

Good afternoon,

I am trying to create a Task in Task Scheduler using a Powershell script.
I need the task to be 'Run with Highest Privileges'.

I am using the following code that I found and modified.  This code runs successfully.

```
$jobname = "Recurring PowerShell Task 2"
$script =  '-File "C:\Users\Paul\Documents\RSYNC\Get-LatestAppLog.ps1" -name ' + '10001.QvdDeletionTest'
$action = New-ScheduledTaskAction –Execute "powershell.exe" -Argument  "$script"
$duration = ([timeSpan]::maxvalue)
$repeat = (New-TimeSpan -hours 3)
$trigger =New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Daily -At 2:00pm

$msg = "Enter the username and password that will run the task"; 
$credential = $Host.UI.PromptForCredential("Task username and password",$msg,"$env:userdomain\$env:username",$env:userdomain)
$username = $credential.UserName
$password = $credential.GetNetworkCredential().Password
$settings = New-ScheduledTaskSettingsSet -AllowStartIfOnBatteries -DontStopIfGoingOnBatteries -StartWhenAvailable -RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable -DontStopOnIdleEnd
Register-ScheduledTask -TaskName $jobname -Action $action -Trigger $trigger -User $username -Password $password -Settings $settings
```

However, if I add in the `-RunLevel Highest` (which was originally part of the `Register-ScheduledTask`  line from the code that I found), the process fails with "Access is Denied"

The user credentials I am using are definitely an Administrator on the pc.  If I go into the Task that is created without the `-RunLevel Highest` and manually change it to 'Run with Highest Privileges' I use the same credentials and it sets the Run Level accordingly.

Please can someone help me so that the script sets the Task to RunLevel Highest?

Answer (score 1):

Opened Powershell ISE as Administrator

Script ran successfully.

Thanks to anyone who was looking into this for me.